# How to change pip version on mac

Tags: python, pip

I have two version of Python3 installed on my mac. One was installed trough `brew`

Now if I do

```
python -V
Python 3.7.6
```

while if I do

```
pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from /Users/myName/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

How can I change `pip` to be as default for `Python 3.7.6`

Comment: You can also use `python -m pip`; then, `pip` will always correspond to the Python executable you're running.

Comment: I get this error `-bash: usr/local/bin/python3.7.3: No such file or director`

Comment: Is that error an actual copy of your error? Because it's missing an initial slash.

Comment: it is the copy of my error

Comment: Also, if you can run `python -V` without problems, `python -m pip` should als run without problems. Note, however, that your error message points to 3.7.3, while your version points to 3.7.6. It would appear `pip` is still being run as an executable, not as a module.

Comment: If I do `python -m pip` I get `-bash: usr/local/bin/python3.7.3: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you execute `type python`?

Comment: @emax Something appears to have been installed improperly.

Comment: sorry, it works!

Comment: So what went wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage Python versions especially on macOS.

Installation (for zsh):

```
brew install pyenv
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Then usage:

```
pyenv install 3.7.6
pyenv global 3.7.6
```

Now python and pip will be pyenv's versions of those programs for Python 3.7.6.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure how this things work on Mac, but general idea is that you should use virtual enviroments for managing your Python versions. Virtualenv simply separates different Python versions and packages (including pip).

IMHO the best way to do that is to use virtualenvwrapper. Here you can find [installation guide](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).